# JavaFX scene builder questions

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm working with JavaFX scene builder and have two questions. 
Fisrt one:"How to add border to Pane in JavaFX scene builder?"
Second one: "How to split cells in HBox?"

Comment: What do you mean with splittings cells in a HBox?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. I meant to join cells.

Comment: For Borders you may check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244923/javafx-fxml-how-do-i-apply-a-border-to-a-pane-or-label-in-my-gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you would want to join HBox cells as you can set the resize behaviour for every child of the hbox.
There is a example in [HBox's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html):

```
//For example, if an hbox needs the TextField to be allocated all extra space:


 HBox hbox = new HBox();
 TextField field = new TextField();
 HBox.setHgrow(field, Priority.ALWAYS);
 hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Search:"), field, new Button("Go"));
```

Joining cells would be possible in a [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) with the row- and/or columnSpan.

```
 GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
 gridpane.add(new Button(), 0, 0, 2, 2); // column=0 row=0, spans over 2 columns and 2 rows
 gridpane.add(new Label(), 3, 1);  // column=3 row=1 (spans over 1 column and 1 row (default))
```

row-/columnSpan and the vertical horizontal Grow can be specified in the Properties bar of the Scene Builder, residing on the right side, by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can set border by using setStyle() and use some styles like -fx-border 
[examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)

P.S. styles are the same, as like css, but with `-fx-` prefix