# javafx & fxml: how do I apply a border to a pane or label in my gui?

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I'm just getting into using fxml and it seems like a really cool idea, except for the fact that I'm having a tough time getting it to work.  Supposedly I'm able to lay out my GUI using a nice markup language, and I can style the elements via CSS.  So I have a label on my GUI, and I would like there to be a solid black border around it, with width=1.  Seems like this should be straightforward -- adapting examples I see here and there in tutorials, etc., I do the following:

```
<Label text="sample text" style="-fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;" />
```

But it doesn't work.  No border appears.  In the Scene Builder there is a text box labelled "Style" in the properties inspector, and I can see the style I have applied appear there, but I don't see a border.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to specify the Border Color as well. Add this to your `Label` tab

```
-fx-border-color:black;
```

In your case the sample code will be :

```
<Label text="sample text" style=" -fx-border-color:black; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;" />
```

Comment: Excellent.  Any insight on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244943/javafx-fxml-how-do-i-set-the-default-selected-item-in-a-choicebox-in-fxml