# FXML how to set choicebox default value

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I've attempted to set the default selected item of my choicebox, however it isn't working as intended...

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="d" value="- Select choice -">
    <String fx:value="hellow"/>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer is answered in the question [JavaFX & FXML: how do I set the default selected item in a ChoiceBox in FXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244943/javafx-fxml-how-do-i-set-the-default-selected-item-in-a-choicebox-in-fxml)

For example when you want to select the second value as default value you can do following in your *FXML* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="choicebox.defaultselection.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <ChoiceBox layoutX="16.0" layoutY="52.0" prefWidth="150.0" value="5 minutes">
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <String fx:value="2 minutes" />
                    <String fx:value="5 minutes" />
                    <String fx:value="15 minutes" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ChoiceBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.setValue("");` for setting the default value.. point to note the `valuename` should be present in `observablearray("","","")`

Example

```
@fxml
private ChoiceBox choiceId; // this is fxml choicebox Id name given in fxml file

ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList("valuename1","valuename2");

choiceId.setValue("valuename1"); // this statement shows default value 

choiceId.setItems(options); // this statement adds all values in choiceBox
```

Comment: for pointing out that the value should be in the observable array, you have my gratitude. I was stucke even while using 'setValue()'.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked many years ago but I didn't like the answers given.  I was recently having the same issue and I finally realized what the problem was. Take this for example:

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="cb_DBEditors" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="192.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="124.0" value="Testing">
   <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
             <String fx:value="SQL Plus" />
             <String fx:value="Something Else" />
        </FXCollections>
   </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

The value you have in the default `value=""` must equal one of the `fx:value` strings.  If it isn't then the `ChoiceBox` will be blank.  To recap, the default value you set must be one of the `fx:value` in your `<items>` list.

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="cb_DBEditors" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="192.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="124.0" value="SQL Plus">
   <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
             <String fx:value="SQL Plus" />
             <String fx:value="Something Else" />
        </FXCollections>
   </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use 'value' then it will set default value for your choice box or even you can display any short message for your choice box:

```
<ChoiceBox value="- Select choice -">
<items>
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
<String fx:value="first choice"></String>
</FXCollections>
</items>*emphasized text*
</ChoiceBox>
```